# checking hidden field is empty or not

Tags: asp.net

i have a

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ListTwoHiddenField" />
```

i have some programming aspect how can i check whether hidden field is empty or not
i mean i want to check that `ListTwiHiddenField.items.cout==0` or empty how can i check this

Comment: Can you post more of the markup? The list that contains this field, the way you are trying to access it. And try to make sure that when you type code in, it is correct - its `Items.Count()`, not `items.cout`.

Comment: no no there is nothing like items.count method i am just writing that my own to explain you people that i want to know that kind of feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HiddenFields don't have an Items collection, they just have a Value property, which is a String. So to check if it's empty all you need is:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListTwoHiddenField.Value)
{
}
```

Or you could use `string.IsEmptyOrWhitespace`, which would check whether the hidden field's value is just [space] characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
    dont check for NUll and Empty in one line 
    like this
    if(HiddenObj.Value != null || HiddenObj.Value.Length > 0)
    {
       //hidden object is not null and have length more than zero that means have some content
    }
    else
    {
    //hidden object is null or have length empty
    }

    this thing is going to fail 
    try like this 
    if(HiddenObj.Value != null)
    {
       if(HiddenObj.Value.Length > 0)
         {
         //hidden object is not null and have length more than zero that means have some content
         }else
        {
         // hidden object value is empty 
        }


    }else
    {
     // hidden object is Null 
    }

// from santosh kakani
```

Comment: or just go with string.IsNullOrEmpty(HiddenObj.Value)?

Comment: or even replace your OR (||) with an AND (&&) in your 1st example because if the 1st condition fails the 2nd isn't checked so no NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check :

```
if(ListTwoHiddenField.Value != String.Empty)
{
    //do code
}
```

No need for checking null also. if you are adding hidden field to aspx page. when page controls initialize itself it will also initialize.